# Cypress 5.2.0 .select() not triggering selection

Tags: cypress

In our app, we have the following dropdown selector:

```
<select class="ng-tns-c77-28" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Banana">
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <!---->
  <option class="ng-tns-c77-28 ng-star-inserted" value="15">Apple</option>
  <option class="ng-tns-c77-28 ng-star-inserted" value="12">Banana</option>
  <option class="ng-tns-c77-28 ng-star-inserted" value="17">Cherry</option>
  <option class="ng-tns-c77-28 ng-star-inserted" value="13">Orange</option>
  <!---->
</select>
```

I'm trying to use `cy.get('select').select("Apple", {force: true});` to select the "Apple" option. When a user selects an option on the dropdown, elements of the page change, with different fields being shown based on which fruit you select.

My issue is that, when trying to select "Apple", Cypress claims to be accurately selecting it, when no change occurs on the page. The dropdown doesn't even change, it continues to show that "Banana" is selected. According to the console, value 15 is being selected, which corresponds with "Apple", but there is no change being made on the page.

This is driving me nuts. Does anybody have any idea what is occurring here?

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas for debugging:

1. Verify using the [Cypress Command Log](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-runner.html#Command-Log) in the Cypress UI that the `cy.get('select')` returns the correct element.
2. Add an expectation which may provide additional inside from Cypress.

   cy.get('select').select('Apple').should('have.value', '17')
3. Try to [select by value](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/select.html#Value) instead of label to see if that has an effect.

   cy.get('select').select('17').should('have.value', '17')

Finally, it is recommend to select elements more granular than element (e.g select).  Consider adding a `data-test` attribute for use when selecting this element (e.g. data-test="fruit-options").  This makes your test code more resilient to change and the concept can be seen throughout the [Cypress Real World App](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/11/introducing-the-cypress-real-world-app/), [a payment application to demonstrate real-world usage of Cypress testing methods, patterns, and workflows](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app).